# How to change a Lift project root package?

Tags: scala, namespaces, refactoring, lift

A standard "Symply Lift" RestHelper [example](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-5.3.html) project features `code`, `code.lib` and `code.model` and `bootstrap.liftweb.Boot` namespaces. I've changed those to `mycompany.myproject.code` e t.c. Now the project compiles ok and Jetty starts just fine but I get `The Requested URL /my/url was not found on this server` error when I try to access what used to work just fine before the refactoring. What may I have forgotten to change? How should I change the packages names safely?

Changing `LiftRules.addToPackages("code")` to `LiftRules.addToPackages("mycompany.myproject.code")` doesn't help.

UPDATE: I've found out that the problem was caused by the fact I've moved `bootstrap.liftweb.Boot` to `mycompany.myproject.bootstrap.liftweb.Boot`. I've moved it back and it is up and working again. But I am still curious how can I customize `bootstrap.liftweb` location as `bootstrap.liftweb.Boot` class differs from project to project and I don't want all of them to have the same full name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own `Boot` class using LiftFilter Setup in `web.xml` as described in [Chapter 3.2 Bootstrap](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-3.html) of [Exploring Lift](http://exploring.liftweb.net).

From the book:

```
<filter>
    ... filter setup here ...
    <init-param>     
        <param-name>bootloader</param-name>
        <param-value>foo.bar.baz.MyBoot</param-value>
    </init-param> 
</filter>
```

where your custom boot class class must subclass `net.liftweb.http.Bootable` and implement the `boot` method.